# Triggering vSphere build via Jenkins pipeline agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My goal is to set up a declarative pipeline job which automatically triggers the vSphere plugin to create a VM on which the build and test runs in a clean environment.

I've configured the vSphere Cloud Plugin in Jenkins' global settings to build slaves with label "appliance-slave", and this does trigger for freestyle jobs with "Restrict where this project can be run" set to that label.  However, the following example pipeline never triggers the vSphere plugin (based on tailing the Jenkins log):

```
pipeline {
   agent {
       label 'appliance-slave'
   }
   stages {
       stage('Test') {
           steps {
                sh "hostname && hostname -i"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I've searched the documentation without any luck.  Is there some configuration option or alternate agent declaration that I'm missing that would allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem; the issue was that I needed to go in to the actual slave configuration and set up the slave there.  The vSphere plugin modifies the slave configuration page to allow exactly what I was trying to do: shutting down and reverting the VM once the build is complete.